# How to insert data to Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have a file Excel contains 4 Sheets, how can I write data to sheet 2 without using OLEDB, and I want to write data cell by cell...
Could any one help me ?

I have a code like this :

```
Excel._Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel._Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\Project Skripsi\\normalisasi.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value2) + 1;

            xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For using worksheet 2 you will have to use this..

```
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
```

This means that xWorkSheet object is pointing to the sheet2 and values you added to the cells would be added to sheet2.

And u can add values to cells using this,

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "YourValue(Could be of any data type)";
```

Answer (score -1):

With Office-Interop you can access the different sheets by using the index on the Worksheet-property in the Workbook object:

```
 //select the first sheet
 Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet) xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
 //select the second sheet
 Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Worksheet) xlWorkBook.Worksheets[2];
```

Comment: What he has used above is also a part of Office-Interop